Find Galois group of polynomials when char F=2
Let $F$ be a field with characteristic 2. Need to calculate the Galois group of $f$ defined as follows
(i)$f = x^3 + x + 1$ ,
(ii)$f = x^3 + x^2 + 1$ .
I know that if $\alpha$ is a root of (i), then so is $\alpha^2$. And hence the splitting field of $f$ over $F$ is $F(\alpha)$. Then how can I find $[F(\alpha):F]$? Is I thinking in the right way?

If you're doing Galois Theory then surely you know that the degree you seek is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$?

@ancientmathematician I know its the degree, but sadly I cannot figure out the minimal polynomial here.TAT .Please teach me how to do it

(A) Let us first deal with the case when $F=\mathbb{F}_2$.
Your $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3+x+1$. This is a cubic polynomial. It is irreducible. (If it were reducible it would have a linear factor, and the only linear polynomials are $x$ and $x+1$ neither of which divides $x^3+x+1$.)
Hence the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $x^3+x+1$, and so $|\mathbb{F}_2[\alpha]:\mathbb{F}_2|=3$.
In fact we now see that $x^3+x+1=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)(x-\alpha^4)$ in the splitting field.
I leave it to you to show that $x^3+x^2+1$ has the same splitting field and that its roots are $\alpha^{-1},\alpha^{-2},\alpha^{-4}$.
(B) In general note that $(x-1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)=x^7-1$, so that every root of $x^3+x+1$ and every root of $x^3+x^2+1$ is a $7$-th root of unity and so lies in $\mathbb{F}_8$.
Hence
(a) either $\mathbb{F}_8\subseteq F$, and in this case $F$ splits both these polynomials;
(b) or $\mathbb{F}_8\not\subseteq F$, and in this case $|F(\alpha):F|=3$ and $F(\alpha)$ splits both polynomials.

Thank a lot! It's helpful to me !
